# Problems streaming Grid/FS to WriteableStream in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, streaming, gridfs

I have Images stored on Grid/FS and in order to improve UI I want to resize all of them to fit within a certain dimension (stretching and squashing effect are outside of scope). Currently the images are returned using the following...

```
FileProvider.prototype.streamFile = function(res, _id, contenttype){
  var properId = this.db.bson_serializer.ObjectID.createFromHexString(_id)
  res.contentType(contenttype)
  var readstream = gfs.createReadStream(properId, {
    "content_type": contenttype,
    "id":true,
    "metadata":{
      "author": "Jackie"
    },
    "chunk_size": 1024*4 })
  readstream.pipe(res)
}
```

This works great but now I want to intercept the image and resize it so my idea was to stream it in-memory than preform a resize using [imagemagik](https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick) (If there is a better way please feel free to tell me).

However, the following code fails to load an image...

```
FileProvider.prototype.streamFile = function(res, _id, contenttype){
  var properId = this.db.bson_serializer.ObjectID.createFromHexString(_id)
  res.contentType(contenttype);
  var readstream = gfs.createReadStream(properId, {
      "content_type": contenttype,
      "id":true,
      "metadata":{
        "author": "Jackie"
      },
      "chunk_size": 1024*4 });
  var writestream = new stream.Stream()
  writestream.writeable = true
  writestream.write = function(data){
    console.log("Streaming.."+data)
  }
  writestream.pipe = function(src){
    console.log("Piping:"+src)
  }
  writestream.end = function (data){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
    console.log("Completed")
  }
  readstream.pipe(writestream)
}
```

This outputs the following to the console...

> undefined
>
> Completed

In other words no data is getting written to the writeStream. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I know this is older, but do you remember off-hand what your solution was?